# Python Random Array of 0s and 1s

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to *randomly* produce an `array` of `n` ones and `m` zeros.

I thought of this solution:

1. produce the ones array (`np.ones`)
2. produce the zeros array (`np.zeros`)
3. combine them to one array (`np.hstack`)
4. shuffle the resulting array (`np.random.shuffle`)

Seems to be not natural as a solution. Some pythonic ideas?

Comment: Do you want an array of _exactly_ `n` ones and `m` zeros, or an array of `n+m` elements that _on average_ will have `n` ones and `m` zeros?

Comment: exactly n ones and m zeros

Comment: By the way, you probably want to use `np.random.shuffle`, not `random.shuffle`.

Comment: Your solution looks perfectly fine and Pythonic to me, if you want exact numbers of ones and zeros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution seems reasonable. It states exactly what it's doing, and does it clearly.

Let's compare your implementation:

```
a = np.hstack((np.ones(n), np.zeros(m)))
np.random.shuffle(a)
```

… with an obvious alternative:

```
a = np.ones(n+m)
a[:m] = 0
np.random.shuffle(a)
```

That might save a bit of time not allocating and moving hunks of data around, but it takes a bit more thought to understand.

And doing it in Python instead of in NumPy:

```
a = np.array([1]*n + [0]*m)
np.random.shuffle(a)
```

… might be a little more concise, but it seems less idiomatically NumPy (in the same way that `np.array([1]*n)` is less idiomatic than `np.ones(n)`), and it's going to be slower and use more memory for no good reason. (You could improve the memory by using `np.fromiter`, but then it's pretty clearly not going to be more concise.)

Of course if you're doing this more than once, the real answer is to factor it out into a function. Then the function's name will explain what it does, and almost any solution that isn't too tortured will be pretty easy to understand…

Answer (score 1):

I'd make an array of n ones and m zeros as

```
a = np.array([1] * n + [0] * m)
```

Then I'd call `np.random.shuffle()` on it.

Comment: Why would you do this? It's going to be slower, and use more memory, and it's hard to see a compensating benefit.

Comment: It's most easily understandable to me (and, so I assume, to coworkers). That's the only thing that counts until memory or speed becomes a problem and this part of the code turns out to be the bottleneck.

Comment: I didn't know about `np.random.shuffle`, I'll edit it to use that.

Comment: What's hard to understand about `np.hstack(np.ones(n), np.zeros(m))`? That says what it does directly, in NumPy terms. Would you say that `np.array([1] * n)` is more readable than `np.ones(n)`?

Comment: Creating lists only to convert them to arrays later is slow for large sizes, better to use `np.ones` and `np.zeros` and `concatenate` them together, exactly as the OP suggested in his question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.random.permutation`:

```
a = numpy.random.permutation([1] * n + [0] * m)
```

or, using arrays instead of an initial list:

```
a = numpy.random.permutation(numpy.concatenate(np.ones(n), np.zeros(m)))
```

(I don't know enough about `numpy` to comment on the difference between `concatenate` and `hstack`; they seem to produce the same results here.)

Comment: Why use `permutation` to make a shuffled copy instead of shuffling it in-place? I can see a benefit in making the whole thing an expression, and in pure Python code I'd probably write something like this, but in NumPy code, it doesn't seem as idiomatic.

Comment: Shuffling in-place may indeed be better. I just noticed that `permutation` seemed to be the `numpy` "equivalent" of pure Python `sorted` (or, rather, of `random.shuffled`, the hypothetical counterpart to `random.shuffle`.)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit strange that `np.random` has an equivalent of `shuffled`, where you don't often want it, but the stdlib's `random` doesn't have one, where you often would want it…

Comment: As for the difference between `concatenate` and `hstack`: if you don't pass an `axis` argument, and you've got 1D arrays, there's no difference at all; it's just a matter of which one you find more readable for a given problem. I think I would have chosen `concatenate` here, but since the OP chose `hstack`, I figured better to stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is suitable, in that it's readable and pythonic.  You didn't say whether memory or performance are considerations.  It's possible that np.random.shuffle is as good as O(m + n), but the other answers suggest that it does more than a single pass to shuffle the values.  You could do it in O(m + n) with only a single pass and no memory overhead like this:

```
import random
m = 600 # zeros
n = 400 # ones

result = []
while m + n > 0:
    if (m > 0 and random.random() < float(m)/float(m + n)):
        result.append(0)
        m -= 1
    else:
        result.append(1)
        n -= 1
```